# Pipe output of awk to sed in single command

Tags: awk, sed

I have a simple file like :

```
a 123
b 234
```

In a second file, I want to replace a string by the value corresponding to a -> "123" **in a single command**.

Is there a way to pipe the result of `grep "a" file1 | awk {print $2}` to `sed s/string/my_output/g file2`

Comment: I did it with a variable, but there probably a better way : var=`grep "a" file1 | awk {'print $2'}` && sed -i s/string/$var/g file2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `awk`

```
cat file1
a 123
b 234
```

```
cat file2
cat
bad hat
```

```
awk -v FS="" 'FNR==NR {split($0,b," ");a[b[1]]=b[2];next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=a[$i]?a[$i]:$i}1' file1 file2
c 123 t
234 123 d   h 123 t
```

---

How does it work.

```
awk -v FS="" '                      # By setting Field Separator to nothing, it works on one and one letter
FNR==NR {                           # This is true only for the first file (file1)
    split($0,arr-b," ")             # Split the data in first file (arr-b[1]=first filed, eks a, arr-b[2]=second field, eks 123
    arr-a[arr-b[1]]=arr-b[2]        # Store this to an array using field 1 as index. arr-a[a]=123 arr-a[b]=234 etc
    next}                           # Skip to next record in file1
    {                               # Run this for file2
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)             # Loop trough on by on letter "c" "a" "t"
        $i=arr-a[$i]?arr-a[$i]:$i}  # Test the letter one by one if its found in array "arr-a", if so use data from array, if not keep value
1                                   # Since this always will be true, do default action "print $0" (print every line)
' file1 file2                       # Read file1 and file2
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of one liner i'm looking for ! Can you explain a little bit please ?

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, try

```
sed 's@^\(.*\) \(.*\)$@s/\1/\2/g@' SimpleFile > substitutions.file
sed -f substitutions.file 2ndFile > 2ndFile.tmp && mv 2ndFile.tmp 2ndFile
```

The first step will create a sed substitions file like

```
s/a/123/g
s/b/234/g
```

which when used as in line2 above, will substitute each a with 123, etc.

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
grep a file1| awk '{print $2}' > tmp.txt
```

This will put '123' in a temporary file.  Then:

```
sed -f script.sed file2
```

Where the contents of script.sed is

```
/string to replace/ {
    r tmp.txt
    d
}
```

This script replaces "string to replace" with the contents of tmp.txt.

Answer (score 0):

here's a pure-Awk solution.  Put the dictionary in 'adict.dat' then pass your input file to the Awk command

### source

```
BEGIN { 
    while(( getline line < "adict.dat" ) > 0 ) {
        $0 = line;
        myvars[$1] = $2;
    }
}

{
    for (varname in myvars) {
        gsub(varname, myvars[varname]);
    }
    print;
}
```

### Example run

```
/bin/echo 'a x b y' | gawk -f arepl.awk
```

### output

```
123 x 234 y
```